# make columns rows python

Tags: python, pandas

hello i have the following code:

```
for j in range(8):                                                         
    b=fran[fran.Año.isin([2020]) & fran.Channel.isin(['CANAL 5'])&fran.Week.isin([j])]  
    c=b[['hour','number']]  
    print(c)
```

I get the output:

```
    |hour| number
   1|12-1|3.1
   2|1-3 |2.3
   3|3-7 |4.6
    |hour| number
   4|7-11|2
   1|12-1|1.2
   2|1-3 |3
   3|3-7 |1.1
   4|7-11|5.6
   ...
    |hour| number
   1|12-1|1
   2|1-3 |1.2
   3|3-7 |5.4
   4|7-11|2.2
```

I would like help to get the following output:

```
 | hour | number1| number2|...|numbern|
1|12-1  |3.1     | 1.2    |...| 1
2|1-3   |2.3     | 3      |...| 1.2
3|3-7   |4.6     | 1.1    |...| 5.4
4|7-11  |2       | 5.6    |...| 2.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to

```
l=[]
for j in range(8):                                                         
    b=fran[fran.Año.isin([2020]) & fran.Channel.isin(['CANAL 5'])&fran.Week.isin([j])]  
    l.append(b[['hour','number']].set_index('hour').rename(columns={'number' : 'number' + str(j)}))
```

Then do `concat`

```
df=pd.concat(l),axis=1).reset_index()
```